# Installing CFW on Ipod using banshee

Tags: 16.04, banshee, ipod, apple

I haven't been able to install Itunes. So I installed Banshee instead. How would I jail break it or install CFW using it? More specifically WhiteD00r

Comment: Are you trying to install iTunes in Ubuntu? If so I would like to do that too as would many others I presume. I believe you can install Windows version of iTunes using Wine within Ubuntu (just google it)  (sorry Nike).

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix iTunes doesn't run effectively under Wine, especially if they are trying to jailbreak the iPhone (and I don't think there's a Linux way to do that)

Comment: @ThomasWard I don't know anything about jailbreaking an iPhone but isn't he talking about iPod? I don't know anything about jailbreaking iPod either.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix iPhone and iPods jailbreakable are both iOS, and both need iTunes for a firmware flash.  Having jail broken a couple past-warranty iPod and iPhones I'm fairly certain it's not achievable without iTunes, and that doesn't function properly under Wine according to latest tests on the WineHQ app DB

Comment: Thanks for the iPhone / iPod shared IOS information. It would be nice if Apple gave away iTunes for Debian/Ubuntu. After all they make money selling songs so they would make a handsome profit.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I'm not asking how to install iTunes I'm wondering if there is an alternative way to jailbreak an iPod on Ubuntu

Comment: @HersheyGamer Thanks for the clarification. I'd still like to see Apple iTunes for Linux. It should be a simple project for them. I had no idea Ubuntu was used to jailbreak iPhones and iPods. You learn something new every day...